# LoadVars() and method POST for swiffty

Tags: google-swiffy

He did not know how someone could remake the piece of code to make it Google swiffty received since I wrote that this was not supported. This is a game in flash as1.

```
on (release) {
    sendscore = new LoadVars();
    sendscore.gscore = _root.Score;
    sendscore.gname = "gamename";
    sendscore.send("index.php?act=Arcade&do=newscore","_self","POST");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [Swiffy only supports AS 2.0 and above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Swiffy#Supports)

Comment: Sure, I know this. Even so, it transferred the game and works up to that part.